# Spring Security with REST architecture

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been looking into a problem with Spring Security for a REST API. And before jumping into implementation I would like to get an expert advice or some sample project on github, if available.

My application will be based on REST API. And will be accessed by two clients:

1. Mobile Phone
2. Web

If I create a REST API with custom login page, then it will always be redirected to Web (as per my understanding). What when I will start consuming it with Mobile Phone?

```
 .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/ui/index.html#/app/dashboard")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/upuser/verifyUser")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
                .loginPage("/ui/index.html#/access/signin")
```

I think from the above code it seems quite obvious that this application will be accessed from two different locations:

1. localhost:8080/api/ for API
2. localhost:8383/ui/ for WEB (Angular JS)

But, I will move both to localhost/api/ & localhost/ui/ by using nginx. So, above two will be accessed by

1. localhost/api/
2. localhost/ui/

So, my second question is what will be the best way to implement spring security:

1. Token Based Authentication
2. Session Based Authentication

Problem is as it's a stateless service so how we are going to implement session based Authentication?

Comment: This is what i'm doing, May be helpful for you to take a right decision. My webapp only handles rest API's with token based authentication. It does not handle the login ui etc. It only send 401 unauthorized status back to client. I have a separate angularjs and mobile modules. AngularJS will handle authentication and redirection via an http interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
You should try this, may be it will help you:

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("container")
public class SOAPSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderDB;


@Override
@Order(1)

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}


@Order(2)
protected void ConfigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderDB);
}

@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/scripts/**","/styles/**","/images/**","/error/**");
  }

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            //To change body of generated methods,
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        }
            })
            .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailure(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                        }
            })
            .loginProcessingUrl("/access/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/access/logout")                
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response, 
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
                }
            })
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .csrf()//Disabled CSRF protection
            .disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented this code to work with mobile and web both? If yes, can you share the code, so that I can take an in-depth look into this

Comment: it works for both web app as well as mobile, I can't share the code, you should try and if you stuck up then I will help to resolve it

Comment: thanks for your response ojus, I have created another question which is showing the implementation, I have done so far. But, still facing an issue. I am new to spring security that's why having lot of issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140375/annotation-based-spring-security-for-rest-api